# Custom Login with Twitter in android

Tags: android, twitter

How to create custom buttons for social login auth for twitter on android application development. By default social media have different SDK, which SDK twitter already has its own button social login but i want to use my own custom button and i wrote some code but getting exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Object.hashCode()' on a null object reference
```

### my code:-

```
TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                    .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
                    .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig("KEY",
                            "KEY"))
                    .debug(true)
                    .build();
            Twitter.initialize(config);
            client = new TwitterAuthClient();
            final TwitterSession session = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
            twitterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    client.requestEmail(session, new Callback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(Result<String> result) {
                            System.out.println("Email is=====>" + result.data);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this

add this gradle line in you project

```
 compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.0.0'
```

Write in your Activity/Fragment

```
         //Your Custom Button
          private ivTwitter;
         //Twitter Login Button
          private TwitterLoginButton ivTwitterMain;

          //init twitter
 TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
                .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(Const.CONSUMER_KEY, Const.CONSUMER_SECRET))
                .debug(false)
                .build();
        Twitter.initialize(config);

        //Write in onCreate method
      ivTwitter = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivTwitter);
      ivTwitterMain = (TwitterLoginButton)view.findViewById(R.id.ivTwitterMain);       
      ivTwitterMain.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                        // Do something with result, which provides a TwitterSession for making API calls
                        TwitterSession session = TwitterCore.getInstance().getSessionManager().getActiveSession();
                        TwitterAuthToken authToken = session.getAuthToken();
                        String token = authToken.token;
                        String secret = authToken.secret;

                        getTwitterUserProfile(session);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                        // Do something on failure
                        Log.d(Const.FRAGMENT_REGISTER, exception.getMessage());
                    }

                });
```

//getTwitterUserProfile

```
private void getTwitterUserProfile(TwitterSession session) {
        AccountService accountService = new TwitterApiClient(session).getAccountService();
        Call<User> callback = accountService.verifyCredentials(true, true, true);
        callback.clone().enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Result<User> result) {
              Log.d("NAME ", result.data.name);
               Log.d("EMAIL", result.data.email);
              Log.d("PICTURE ",  result.data.profileImageUrl);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(TwitterException exception) {

            }
        });
    }
```

at last generate Click event of custom button

```
ivTwitter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //twitter login button
                ivTwitterMain.performClick(); 
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**Try to implement Below code Snipeet**/

First Download the Twitter Library from Below mentioned Link:
Link -> http://twitter4j.org/maven2/org/twitter4j/twitter4j-core/4.0.4/

Add the library to your build.gradle

/******************************************************/

Make "Twitter_Handler" Class inside your project

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import twitter4j.TwitterFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import twitter4j.auth.AccessToken;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.Window;

public class Twitter_Handler 
{
public static Twitter twitterObj;
private final TwitterSession mSession;
private AccessToken mAccessToken;
private final CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer mHttpOauthConsumer;
private final OAuthProvider mHttpOauthprovider;
private final String mConsumerKey;
private final String mSecretKey;
private final ProgressDialog mProgressDlg;
private TwDialogListener mListener;
private final Activity context;

public static final String CALLBACK_URL = "twitterapp://connect";
private static final String TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";
private static final String TWITTER_AUTHORZE_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";
private static final String TWITTER_REQUEST_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";

public Twitter_Handler(Activity context, String consumerKey,String secretKey) 
{
    this.context = context;

    twitterObj = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    mSession = new TwitterSession(context);
    mProgressDlg = new ProgressDialog(context);

    mProgressDlg.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    mConsumerKey = consumerKey;
    mSecretKey = secretKey;

    mHttpOauthConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(mConsumerKey,mSecretKey);

    String request_url = TWITTER_REQUEST_URL;
    String access_token_url = TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL;
    String authorize_url = TWITTER_AUTHORZE_URL;

    mHttpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(request_url,access_token_url, authorize_url);
    mAccessToken = mSession.getAccessToken();

    configureToken();
}

public void setListener(TwDialogListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

private void configureToken()
{
    if (mAccessToken != null) 
    {
        twitterObj.setOAuthConsumer(mConsumerKey, mSecretKey);
        twitterObj.setOAuthAccessToken(mAccessToken);
    }
}

public boolean hasAccessToken() {
    return (mAccessToken == null) ? false : true;
}

public void resetAccessToken() {
    if (mAccessToken != null) {
        mSession.resetAccessToken();

        mAccessToken = null;
    }
}

public String getUsername() {
    return mSession.getUsername();
}

public void updateStatus(String status) throws Exception {
    try {
        twitterObj.updateStatus(status);
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

public void authorize()
{
    mProgressDlg.setMessage("Loading ...");
    mProgressDlg.show();

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String authUrl = "";
            int what = 1;

            try {
                authUrl = mHttpOauthprovider.retrieveRequestToken(mHttpOauthConsumer, CALLBACK_URL);
                what = 0;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 1, 0, authUrl));
        }
    }.start();
}

public void processToken(String callbackUrl) 
{
    mProgressDlg.setMessage("Finalizing ...");
    mProgressDlg.show();

    final String verifier = getVerifier(callbackUrl);

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int what = 1;

            try {
                mHttpOauthprovider.retrieveAccessToken(mHttpOauthConsumer,verifier);

                mAccessToken = new AccessToken(mHttpOauthConsumer.getToken(),mHttpOauthConsumer.getTokenSecret());

                configureToken();

                User user = twitterObj.verifyCredentials();



                mSession.storeAccessToken(mAccessToken, user.getName());

                what = 0;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(what, 2, 0));
        }
    }.start();
}

private String getVerifier(String callbackUrl) {
    String verifier = "";

    try {
        callbackUrl = callbackUrl.replace("twitterapp", "http");

        URL url = new URL(callbackUrl);
        String query = url.getQuery();

        String array[] = query.split("&");

        for (String parameter : array) {
            String v[] = parameter.split("=");

            if (URLDecoder.decode(v[0]).equals(
                    oauth.signpost.OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER)) {
                verifier = URLDecoder.decode(v[1]);
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return verifier;
}

private void showLoginDialog(String url) {
    final TwDialogListener listener = new TwDialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(String value) {

            processToken(value);

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String value) {
            mListener.onError("Failed opening authorization page");
        }
    };

    new TwitterDialog(context, url, listener).show();
}

@SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        mProgressDlg.dismiss();

        if (msg.what == 1)
        {
            if (msg.arg1 == 1)
                mListener.onError("Error getting request token");
            else
                mListener.onError("Error getting access token");
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (msg.arg1 == 1)
                showLoginDialog((String) msg.obj);
            else
                mListener.onComplete("");
        }
    }
};

public interface TwDialogListener {
    public void onComplete(String value);

    public void onError(String value);
}

 }

 /******************************************************/

 Now Make "Twitt_LoginOnly" Class inside your project

 import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Twitt_LoginOnly {

private final Twitter_Handler mTwitter;
private final Activity activity;
public static interface LoginResult
{
    public abstract void loginResult(String message);
}
public LoginResult loginCallback;



public Twitt_LoginOnly( Activity act, String consumer_key, String consumer_secret,LoginResult loginCallback) {
    this.activity = act;
    mTwitter = new Twitter_Handler(activity, consumer_key, consumer_secret);
    this.loginCallback = loginCallback;
}

public void loginToTwitter() 
{

    mTwitter.setListener(mTwLoginDialogListener);

    if (mTwitter.hasAccessToken())
    {
        // this will post data in asyn background thread
        //showTwittDialog();
        showToast("Already Logged in");
        loginCallback.loginResult("Already Logged in");
    } 
    else 
    {

        mTwitter.authorize();
    }

}
private final TwDialogListener mTwLoginDialogListener = new TwDialogListener() {

    @Override
    public void onError(String value) {

        loginCallback.loginResult("Login Failed");


        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showToast("Login Failed");
                mTwitter.resetAccessToken();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(String value) 
    {
        //showTwittDialog();

        loginCallback.loginResult("Login Successfully");

        showToast("Login Successfully");
    }
};

void showToast(final String msg) 
{
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(activity, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}   
  }

 /******************************************************/

 Now Implement the Code in your Activity or Fragment Class

  twitter_login = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login);

  twitter_login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View button)
            {
                        Twitt_LoginOnly logintwitter = new Twitt_LoginOnly(Activity.this,
                        “YOUR TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY”, “YOUR TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET”, new Twitt_LoginOnly.LoginResult()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void loginResult(String message)
                            {
                                TwitterSession twittersession = new TwitterSession(Activity.this);
                                if (twittersession.getAccessToken() != null)
                                {



                                }
                            }
                        });
                        logintwitter.loginToTwitter();


            }

        });
```